# C# windows phone silverlight передача изображения с сервера

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

Есть серверное приложение на пк на c# на сокетах. Есть клиент-приложение на wp по примеру [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx). Нужно передать изображение и вывести в приложении wp.Передаю размер, побайтово передаю изображение, размер при получении совпадает. При попытке перевести в Bitmapimage происходит вылет приложения. Проверял на клиенте-пк,изображение получается и выводится.Выводил побайтово полученное на wp и на сервере, совпадает цифра в цифру.Проблема в переводе byte[] в Bitmapimage. Взял стандартную картинку /Assets/BadgeLogo.png. В приложении перевел в byte[] , потом обратно, все работает. Т.е метод правильный, но с данными с сервера не работает. Скопировал ту же стандартную картинку на сервер, вывел побайтово и сравнил с выводом в приложении. Разные. Видимо, bitmap и bitmapimage по-разному представляют изображение? Начало, как подозреваю, отвечает за расширение и потому совпадает. Что делать дальше - я не знаю, перепробовал разные способы представления bitmap в byte[] , везде результат одинаковый и приводит к вылетам приложения.Как Bitmap или Image на сервере на обычном c# передать в приложение на windows phone 8.1 silverlight в BitmapImage, с сервера на клиент?

в приложении использую:

```
public static BitmapImage BytesToImage(byte[] bytes)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
    finally { bitmapImage = null; }
}
```

на сервере:

```
   public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```